# visual studio 2012 parallelism with openmp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, parallel-processing, openmp

I am studying computer architecture in the university.

I have a home work which making convolution faster using parallelism(openMP).

For now I made convolution code (your_convolution) with omp, but It did not be faster at all!

I'm using visual studio 2012.

How can i make it faster??

here's whole convolution's code.

give me some help.

```
#include <intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

void convolution(float* output, float* input, float* filter, int width, int height, int r)
{
    assert(output!=NULL && input!=NULL && filter!=NULL && width>0 && height>0 && r>0);

    int w1=width-1;
    int h1=height-1;
    int fwidth=2*r+1;

    int i, j, di, dj, ii, jj;

    float sum;

    for (i=0;i<height;++i)
    {
        for (j=0;j<width;++j)
        {
            sum=0;
            for (di=-r;di<=r;++di)
            {
                ii=i+di;
                ii=max(min(ii,h1),0);

                for (dj=-r;dj<=r;++dj)
                {
                    jj=j+dj;
                    jj=max(min(jj,w1),0);

                    sum+=filter[dj+r+(di+r)*fwidth]*input[jj+ii*width];
                }
            }
            output[j+i*width]=sum;
        }
    }
}

void your_convolution(float* output, float* input, float* filter, int width, int height, int r)
{
// write your code here //
    assert(output != NULL && input != NULL && filter != NULL && width>0 && height>0 && r>0);

    int w1 = width - 1;
    int h1 = height - 1;
    int fwidth = 2 * r + 1;

    int i, j, di, dj, ii, jj;

    float sum;
        omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel
    {


    for (i = 0; i<height; ++i)
    {

        for (j = 0; j<width; ++j)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (di = -r; di <= r; ++di)
            {
                ii = i + di;
                ii = max(min(ii, h1), 0);

         #pragma omp parallel for 
                    for (dj = -r; dj <= r; ++dj)
                    {
                        jj = j + dj;
                        jj = max(min(jj, w1), 0);

                        sum += filter[dj + r + (di + r)*fwidth] * input[jj + ii*width];

                }

            }
            output[j + i*width] = sum;
        }
    }

}
}


int main()
{
    // load the image
    int width=1920; // width of the image
    int height=1080;    // height of the image
    int len=width*height;   // pixels in the image

    int i, j, ii, jj, i2;

    float* data=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*len);  // buffer to load the image
    float* output=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*len);    // output buffer
    FILE* fp=fopen("../image.dat", "rb");   // open the image, assume that the bld directory is a subdirectory to the src directory
    fread(data, sizeof(float), width*height, fp);   // load the float values, the image is gray.
    fclose(fp);

    // set the filter
    int radius=3;   // filter radius
    float sigma=(float)(radius/3.0);    // standard deviation of the Gaussian filter
    float beta=(float)(-0.5/(sigma*sigma)); // coefficient exp(beta*x*x)
    int fwidth=2*radius+1;  // width of the filter
    int flen=fwidth*fwidth; // number of elements in the filter
    float* filter=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*flen);   // filter buffer
    float sum_weight=0; // we want to normalize the filter weights
    for (i=-radius;i<=radius;++i)
    {
        ii=(i+radius)*fwidth;
        i2=i*i;
        for (j=-radius;j<=radius;++j)
        {
            jj=j+radius+ii;
            filter[jj]=exp(beta*(i2+j*j));
            sum_weight+=filter[jj];
        }
    }

    sum_weight=(float)(1.0/sum_weight);
    for (i=0;i<flen;++i)
        filter[i]*=sum_weight;  // now the weights are normalized to sum to 1

    clock_t start=clock();
    convolution(output, data, filter, width, height, radius);
    clock_t finish=clock();

    double duration = (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf( "convolution naive: %2.3f seconds\n", duration );

    float* output2=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*len);   // output buffer

    start=clock();
    your_convolution(output2, data, filter, width, height, radius);
    finish=clock();

    double duration2 = (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf( "your convolution: %2.3f seconds\n", duration2 );

    double sum=0;
    for (i=0;i<len;++i)
        sum+=fabs(output[i]-output2[i]);

    printf("difference of the outputs=%lf\n", sum);

    printf( "The performance of your convolve is %2.1f times higher than convolution naive.\n", duration/duration2);

    free(data);
    free(filter);
    free(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your  course material may  be more  concise  than a  full answer.  It should cover howto  measure  performance. Avoid nested  parallelism at least  at  first.  Your  compiler will not auto     -vectorize  so  you  don't have a  high bar to  overcome.

Comment: In particular you must heed your lessons about reduction and variable scope.